# Generating points along line with specifying the origin of point generation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, point-creation

I have been trying to generate points along a line with a distance of 500m. We can do this in several ways using tools like "Points along Geometry". However, my problem is that I do not know how to generate points in a specific direction along the line.

I tried using "Points along Geometry", but there is no option to specify the origin. Below you can see what I get using "Points along Geometry".

The problem is that the generation is going down to up and I want it up to down. Is it possible to choose the origin of the line to start generating points?

[image].

Answer (score 6):

The tool [`Points along Geometry`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgispointsalonglines) follows line direction and thus begins where the line has the first vertex (start point). To start from the other end (the last vertex, end point), reverse the line direction:

Use Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>[Reverse line direction](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#reverse-line-direction)</kbd>, then create the points on the resulting line.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a Virtual Layer using functions [`ST_Line_Interpolate_Equidistant_Points`](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html) and [`ST_Reverse`](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html)

Replace `road` with the name of your layer.

To get the point starting from line starts:

```sql
SELECT row_number() over() as id, ST_Line_Interpolate_Equidistant_Points(geometry, 500.0) as geometry
FROM road
```

To start from the line ends, reverse it:

```sql
SELECT row_number() over() as id, ST_Line_Interpolate_Equidistant_Points(St_Reverse(geometry), 500.0) as geometry
FROM road
```

You will get a multipoint output. You can convert them to single parts with ["Multipart To Singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use the following expression to create points at a regular interval along a line. Set the interval distance in line 1 (in my example: `80`). Line 2 is for the option you're looking for, "specify the origin": change `0` to `1` to start the creation of the points from the other side (starting from the line's end point). For this, I used the function [`reverse()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#reverse), together with an [`if()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#if) clause (line 7).

Use the expression with [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) (for visual purpose/testing the result in realtime) or [Geoemtry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (for actual geometries) - [see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814).

*By the way: if you want to add a start offset, in line 6 simply replace `0` by the distance you want the first point to offset. For end offset, in the same line add `-100` (or whatever distance) directly after length($geometry) - before the comma.*

```
with_variable ('interval',80,  -- distance between points
with_variable ('direction',1,  -- set to 1 to reverse line direction (start creating points from the line's opposite end)
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach(
        generate_series (0, length($geometry),@interval),
        line_interpolate_point (
            if(@direction=0,$geometry,reverse($geometry)), 
            @element)
        )
    )
))
```

*The expression, used here with Geometry Generator; lines start at the left, but points are being created starting from the right because in line 2, tha variable `@direction` is set to `1`:*
[image]